# RDP Access Is Mistakenly Restricted via Firewall Any Way To Connect Again?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, windows-firewall

I was trying to add an ip address to windows firewall for remote desktop connection but I don't know why now I can't access to server via rdp even from old ips. I have administrator user and password of the remote machine. Is there any way  to connect again via rdp?

Server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition

Edit: Also I have another server on the same network which I can connect via rdp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can do remote registry, remote service console or psexec to the box you can shut down the windows firewall and / or update the rules to allow yourself back in. My preferred method is with psexec.

Assuming you can psexec the command should be:

```
psexec \\remotecomputername netsh firewall set service remoteadmin enable
psexec \\remotecomputername netsh firewall set service remotedesktop enable
```

EDIT - these are depreciated under Server 2008 but they should still work.

You also may want to execute this command from the other server on the same network.